# Pyspark not able to read from bigquery table

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery

I am running the below code to pull a bigquery table using Pyspark. The spark session has been initiated without any issue but I am not able to connect to the table in public dataset. Here is the error that I get from running the script.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('Optimize BigQuery Storage') \
  .config('spark.jars.packages', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-3.1-bigquery-0.27.1-preview.jar') \
  .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .load("bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/actAv.png

Comment: Are you running the code inside a pyspark kernel ? If yes , can you try to run the code in a Python Kernel? It should allow the sparksession configuration inside the python kernel. You can also refer to this [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Top%20words%20in%20Shakespeare%20by%20work.ipynb)

Comment: Hi Kiran, thanks for the reply. I am running that in the python kernel.

Comment: Your code runs fine on my local environment.Can you change url to  `gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar`and try again.